# What’s a single word that means Contagious Happiness

Tags: single-word-requests

I am searching for a single word that means *contagious happiness* or *infectious happiness*.

Comment: *"A Dane crew consisting of Down syndrome kids."* What? Is that meant to be some kind of joke? If it is, I find it a bit offensive and would think of coming up with a different example. If it's *not* a joke, but you mean it literally, you'll have to give more context.

Comment: Please could you construct a sentence in which you would use the word.

Comment: @JasonBassford I'm note sure what you're finding offensive. Certainly more context will help, but if you have a group of children and you want to give that group a name, that's not a problem. (Although it is off topic.) I see it as similar to naming a school house. I'm assuming Savanna is in some way a care taker for these children.

Comment: @MattE.Эллен To me, with the smiley face at the end of the sentence, Down children are being made the object of ridicule. It's taking a medical condition and saying it's an example of *contagious happiness or infectious happiness*. I find it disrespectful and minimizing. I'm not saying it's intentionally offensive, but it bothers me and it might bother those people who have actual experience with Down syndrome even more. But that's also why I asked for clarification. The smiley face makes it *sound* like a joke at the group's expense.

Comment: I've known people with Down syndrome, and their families and caregivers. As with any other group of people, they don't like being lumped together and characterized in a particular and stereotypical way—it depersonalizes them. It's fine to say that a *person* is one way or another, but it's not fine to say that *"all of them"* are that way.

Comment: @JasonBassford: The OP is apparently looking to do something nice with respect to a group of kids who happen to have Down's Syndrome. Do you think there are no such groups? Must one never refer to them? What's next? Can we never refer to participants in the Special Olympics?

Comment: @JasonBassford - I think it's fairly obvious that OP is trying to come up with a name for a dance troupe that consists of disabled children. That being said, it's still 'chatter' unless he can actually give an example of how the word is going to be used.

Comment: @Richard so why remove all the context? Why remove reference to the dance crew? It's *not* chatter, it's context, and it helps explains why the OP is not happy with "contagious/infectious happiness".

Comment: @Mari-LouA - I also didn't vote to re-open. The question should remain closed until OP makes their intention more clear.

Comment: @Richard and who did?! I don't see anyone saying the question should be reopened. The OP, Savanna, has never came back either. If they cared, they would have.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly a contagious happiness, but if you derive happiness from someone's else happiness, then it is called **confelicitous** happiness. In simple words, if you see someone happy, you feel their happiness. Thus, it makes you happy.

Confelicitous is an adjective, the noun form is

1) YourDictionary: https://www.yourdictionary.com/confelicity

2) Wikitionary: https://www.yourdictionary.com/confelicity

3) Definition.net: https://www.definitions.net/definition/confelicity

Confelicity (uncountable noun)

> (rare) Pleasure in another's happiness.

Answer (score -2):

If you need a new word for this project it may be a blend '***HAPPIDEMIC***'.

This is the result of telescoping *Happiness* and *Epidemic*.

The second noun is connected both with medicine and social life.

According to Merriam-Webster's Dictionary:

**EPIDEMIC**

1: an outbreak of disease that spreads quickly and affects many individuals at the same time

2: an outbreak or product of sudden rapid spread, growth, or development

(https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/epidemic)

Comment: +1 for neologism :)